# Url without php suffix with same name directory

Tags: php, redirect, nginx

I would like to configure our Nginx server to server PHP files without their suffix. The issue is that we have directory in the same name of the file and I don't want to move the file under index.php inside the same directory.

Here is the file structure

```
/www-root/index.php
/www-root/xyz.php
/www-root/xyz/amit.php
```

I managed to get the php suffix to be removed and I would like to access both of the urls as follow:

```
www.example.com/xyz
www.example.com/xyz/amit.php
```

I don't want to move xyz.php to /xyz/index.php since that way there will be a forward slash at the suffix of the URL (which is something I would like to avoid).

I can access www.example.com/xyz.php but when I'm trying to access www.example.com/xyz it will redirect to www.example.com/xyz/ and will fail on 404.

Below is my Nginx conf file:

```
  location / {
            try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
  }
  location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
  }
  location @extensionless-php {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please help - thanks!

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64162356/how-redirect-from-file-php-to-file-on-nginx/64162551#64162551) answer does exactly what you've asked for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How redirect from /file.php to /file on nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64162356/how-redirect-from-file-php-to-file-on-nginx)