# How redirect from /file.php to /file on nginx?

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, seo

I'm currently hiding the .php extension from the urls on my nginx server with this configuration:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}

location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}
```

This is working perfectly, but how can I make nginx not allow adding the .php extension?. In my example if you manually delete the .php it works but if you add it it remains permanent in the url.

Comment: What behavior do you want from nginx for that type of URLs? 301 redirection, 404 not found, something else?

Comment: @IvanShatsky I would like that if the user tries to access file.php automatically nginx redirects to file

Comment: Although you deleted your second question I saw it and spend some time playing with all of this, check an update to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect those requests permanently with HTTP 301 code try

```
rewrite ^(.*)\.php$ $1 permanent;
```

Put this directive before your `location` blocks.

**Update**

After this being answered, OP asked another question (now being deleted) - what if you have the following webroot structure:

```
webroot
|
+-- index.php (PHP file)
|
+-- somename.php (PHP file)
|
+-- somename (folder)
|   |
|   +-- index.php (PHP file)
|
+-- someothername (folder)
    |
    +-- index.php (PHP file)
```

Previous solution makes it impossible to serve `somename.php` file, because the request to `http://example.com/somename` would be redirected by `try_files` directive to `http://example.com/somename/` and in next turn would be served with `somename/index.php` file.

This can be solved, but you'll have to stop using `index` and `try_files` directives and emulate their behavior with your own request processing logic. This is what I've ended up with:

```
map $original_uri $maybe_slash {
    ~/$      '';
    default  '/';
}

server {

    ...

    if ($original_uri = '') {
        set $original_uri $uri;
    }

    # redirect requests of '/somepath/somefile.php' to '/somepath/somefile'
    rewrite ^(.*)\.php$ $1 pemanent;

    location / {

        # this emulates 'try_files $uri $uri/ ...' directive behavior and redirects '/some/path'
        # to '/some/path/' if 'some/path.php' file does not exists, but 'some/path' folder exists
        # and there are 'some/path/index.html' file in that folder
        set $check_redirect $rewrited$maybe_slash;
        if ( $check_redirect = '1/' ) {
           return 301 $original_uri/$is_args$args;
        }

        if ( -f $document_root$uri.php ) { rewrite ^ $uri.php last; }

        # this emulates 'index index.php index.html' directive behavior
        if ( -f $document_root$uri${maybe_slash}index.php ) {
            set $rewrited 1;
            rewrite ^ $uri${maybe_slash}index.php last;
        }
        if ( -f $document_root$uri${maybe_slash}index.html ) {
            set $rewrited 1;
            rewrite ^ $uri${maybe_slash}index.html last;
        }

        # if a request for an absent resource should be served with some backend
        # controller, it is ok to use some 'try_files' directive here like
        # try_files $uri /index.php?path=$original_uri;

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

        # this emulates 'try_files $uri $uri/ ...' directive behavior and redirects '/some/path'
        # to '/some/path/' if 'some/path.php' file does not exists, but 'some/path' folder exists
        # and there are 'some/path/index.php' file in that folder
        set $check_redirect $rewrited$maybe_slash;
        if ( $check_redirect = '1/' ) {
           return 301 $original_uri/$is_args$args;
        }

        # no 'try_files $uri =404'  or 'include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf' here, this location
        # can be reached only if requested PHP file is really exists in webroot folder
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$uri;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;

    }

}
```

With this configuration and webroot structure given above

- request to `http://example.com/` would be served with `webroot/index.php` file;
- request to `http://example.com/somename` would be served with `webroot/somename.php` file;
- request to `http://example.com/somename.php` would be redirected to `http://example.com/somename` and served with `webroot/somename.php` file;
- request to `http://example.com/somename/` would be served with `webroot/somename/index.php` file;
- request to `http://example.com/someothername` would be redirected to `http://example.com/someothername/` (since no `webroot/someothername.php` file exists) and served with `webroot/someothername/index.php` file.

**Important note about custom HTTP error pages**

If you have some custom error page, for example `webroot/error/404.php` for HTTP 404 error, instead of usual way to define it like

```
error_page 404 /error/404.php;
```

you'd need to skip `.php` extension of that file:

```
error_page 404 /error/404;
```