# Why the file can´t be openned on Nginx by browser?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I'm trying to hide the last slash with this code:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

Im doing this for to achieve this:

```
example.com/file

example.com/file/file2
```

This work because on my browser I see `/file` but the browser show me `The page isn't redirecting properly`.
What is not correct? This is my source: http://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/nginx-remove-trailing-slash/

UPDATE:

```
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name _;

rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
rewrite ^(.*)\.php$ $1 permanent;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}

location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you are using `try_files $uri $uri/` directive in your main `location` block and those `/file` and `/file/file2` are real folders under your webroot, you'd got an infinitive redirection loop - from `/file` to `/file/` via `try_files` directive and from `/file/` to `/file` via your `rewrite` rule. I suggest you to include your full `server` block to your question (of course except real server name, certs paths, etc).

Comment: @IvanShatsky I just update it. Im testing and when I allow show the extension .php and I edit the code to rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1.php permanent; it work. But when I hide the .php this stop of work

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64162356/how-redirect-from-file-php-to-file-on-nginx) your question too?

Comment: @IvanShatsky Yes cant reset password

Comment: Check the update I recently wrote to that answer. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: @IvanShatsky Wow! speechless, can you contact me on private?

Comment: Write to ivan.shatsky(at)gmail.com

Comment: @IvanShatsky The only problem is, now I cant receive 404 page only 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: On my test VM its ok, I've got 404 when I request an absent resource. Can you show corresponding line from nginx error log?

Comment: @IvanShatsky This -> 2020/10/02 19:52:15 [error] 20008#20008: *1 could not find named location "@extensionless-php", client: MY IP HERE, server: MY DOMAIN HERE, request: "GET /failwebsiteexample HTTP/1.1", host: "MY DOMAIN HERE"

Comment: I'm not using that naming location in my second example. I'm not using any `try_files` directives too. The whole request processing mechanism is completely different from what you are using in your config, check the example carefully.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Fixed, please read email thanks

Comment: Does everything works as expected now?

Comment: @IvanShatsky Yes all perfect

Comment: @IvanShatsky What do you mean with :         # no 'try_files $uri =404'  or 'include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf' here, this location? I cant put try_files $uri =404 on location ~ \.php$ {} for custom my 404 page?

Comment: It isn't the way that custom 404 pages are defined. You'd need to add `error_page 404 /path/to/your/404/page` (without `.php` part) directive to your nginx config if your real 404 PHP hadler is `path/to/your/404/page.php`.

Comment: That `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` block could be reached only if `if ( -f $document_root$uri.php ) { ... }` check passed, i.e. corresponding `$uri.php` file exists, so `try_files $uri =404` is meaningless in that block.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Good!!

Comment: Added custom HTTP error page info to the main answer.