# Remove the .php extension on all pages (NGINX)

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

Having tried all the solutions on Stack, I was not able to remove the .php extension.

I managed to make the URLs accessible: [www.mydomain.com/login](http://www.mydomain.com/login)
but the user can always change the URL to [www.mydomain.com/login.php](http://www.mydomain.com/login.php) and I'd like to avoid that.

Here is a part of my config :

```
    location / {
                try_files $uri $uri.html  $uri/ @extensionless-php;
                index index.html index.htm index.php;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
         try_files $uri =404;
         include fastcgi_params;
         fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
     }

     location @extensionless-php {
          rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
     }
```

Comment: Maybe you could use a router instead of using the web server to serve files ?

Comment: I don't like to use router

Comment: To remove `.php` from the original request, use: `if ($request_uri ~ ^(.*)\.php(\?.*)?$ { return 301 $1$2; }`

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64162356/how-redirect-from-file-php-to-file-on-nginx/64162551#64162551) one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

For `.html` extensions you just have to add this

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

If you want to add a **trailing slash** at the end you can ignore the code above and insert the code below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

If you're using **[GoDaddy](https://godaddy.com/)** you need to enable `MultiViews` at the top of your `.htaccess` file

```
Options +MultiViews
```

Comment: Why do you aswer a question about nginx with the apache solution? It isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: Jikes my bad, somehow I didn't even realize it